How well are we able to determine diet of an animal based on teeth?
Just by looking at teeth and jaws of extinct are we able to say what specifically species was eating? For example gray wolves eat mainly large herbivores like deer compared to red foxes who in addition to hunting eat fruits, eggs grain and other. But when I look at replica of grey wolf jaw and replica of red fox jaw I don't see many differences.
What other factors are taken in when determining diet besides direct observation?

Maybe a combined approach of jaw morphology + metagenomic analysis? We can tell an animal is a predator or not based on how the eyes are positioned, so maybe the big plus the subtle differences in jaw morphology and a genomic validation could shed light on your question. The accuracy is another story!

Pretty well.
you don't see many diffrences between wolves and foxes because there is not much diffrence in their diet. During the parts of the year where they are avialiable fruit makes up a majority of a wolfs diet. the trick is that is only a small part of the year. Somthing like a encyclopedia is only going to give you a breif overview not a detailed breakdown of an animals diet.
More detailed source
for instance we can see a shift in diet to more grain in early dogs due both to dental anatomy and genetics (digestive enzymes) https://www.jstor.org/stable/29775234
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0305440392900499
The biggest limitation is for teeth that don't match any living animal, this can be much more difficult, we see this is some dinosaur groups. Although you can still say, primary herbivore, primarily carnivore, or the like. you also combine teeth and jaw morphology with the rest of the anatomy. For instance the neck anatomy (specificaly the size and shape of the supporting nuchal ligment) can tell you whether an herbivore is primarily a ground feeder or a browser. This matches what we see in living antelope so again living animals are the  best measure.

I didn't know that wolves have similar diet, so far on internet I've only seen articles talking about wolves eating meat and no mention of fruits etc.
(And the first link says Access Denied)

@Graphenjoyer the problem you have is the word "articles", not great sources for detailed science. I suggest searching google scholar. but here are a few more sources. https://wildlife.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/wsb.1065 and https://rcin.org.pl/ibs/dlibra/publication/27793?tab=1&language=en obligate carnivores are extrememly rare.

@Graphenjoyer Dont feel bad even searching papers can be confusing since a paper about prey selection may barely mention plant matter if they include it at all even when talking about diet. wplves eating berries is not sexy enough to make it into common articles with only a few exceptions and then only for the shock value , https://wildlife.org/wsb-blueberries-surprisingly-important-in-wolf-diet/

wikipedia is a rare exception and can be a good start. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf
